# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone CONTENT_FILTER_URI is not loading correct data

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to list all the available phone numbers with display name from contacts app in a ListView with search. Also if a contact has more than one phone number, it has to be displayed in separate list item (as different contact not as same contact in Contacts App).

I've successfully retrived all the phone numbers with display name and displayed in ListView. Multiple phone numbers of a contact also displayed as separate contact.

But, when I search - either it gives irrelevant phone number for the display name or it fails to filter when I entered single character. Please suggest on this.

Here is my code:

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

// Defines a tag for identifying log entries
private static final String TAG = "ContactsListFragment";

private ContactsAdapter mAdapter; // The main query adapter
private String mSearchTerm; // Stores the current search query term

// Contact selected listener that allows the activity holding this fragment to be notified of
// a contact being selected
private OnContactsInteractionListener mOnContactSelectedListener;

/**
 * Fragments require an empty constructor.
 */
public ContactsListFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Let this fragment contribute menu items
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

     // Create the main contacts adapter
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Inflate the list fragment layout
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up ListView, assign adapter and set some listeners. The adapter was previously
    // created in onCreate().
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        // Assign callback listener which the holding activity must implement. This is used
        // so that when a contact item is interacted with (selected by the user) the holding
        // activity will be notified and can take further action such as extracting the contact
        //details and pass it to AddNewUserDialogFragment
        mOnContactSelectedListener = (OnContactsInteractionListener) activity;  
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() 
                + " must implement OnContactsInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    // Gets the Cursor object currently bound to the ListView
    final Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();

    // Moves to the Cursor row corresponding to the ListView item that was clicked
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final String displayName = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
    final String mobileNumb = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.NUMBER);
    mOnContactSelectedListener.onContactSelected(displayName, mobileNumb);

}
 /**
 * Called when ListView selection is cleared, for example
 * when search mode is finished and the currently selected
 * contact should no longer be selected.
 */
private void onSelectionCleared() {
    // Uses callback to notify activity this contains this fragment
    mOnContactSelectedListener.onSelectionCleared();

    // Clears currently checked item
    getListView().clearChoices();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){

    // Inflate the menu items
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_list_menu, menu);
    // Locate the search item
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    //sets up and configures the ActionBar SearchView
    final SearchManager mSearchManager = (SearchManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    // Retrieves the SearchView from the search menu item
    final SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    // Assign searchable info to SearchView
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(mSearchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    // Set listeners for SearchView
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Updates
            // the search filter, and restarts the loader to do a new query
            // using the new search string.
            String newFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;

            // Don't do anything if the filter is empty
            if(mSearchTerm == null && newText == null){
                return true;
            }

            // Don't do anything if the new filter is the same as the current filter
            if(mSearchTerm != null && mSearchTerm.equals(newText)){
                return true;
            }

            // Updates current filter to new filter
            mSearchTerm = newFilter;

            // Restarts the loader. This triggers onCreateLoader(), which builds the
            // necessary content Uri from mSearchTerm.
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID, null, ContactsListFragment.this);

            return true;
        }
    });

    searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Nothing to do when the action item is expanded
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // When the user collapses the SearchView the current search string is
            // cleared and the loader restarted.
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)){
                onSelectionCleared();
            }
            mSearchTerm = null;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID, null, ContactsListFragment.this);
            return true;
        }
    });

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID, null, ContactsListFragment.this);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)){
        // Saves the current search string
        outState.putString(SearchManager.QUERY, mSearchTerm);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader starts");
    //If this is the loader for finding contacts in the Contacts Provider
    if(id == ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID){
        Uri contentUri;

        // There are two types of searches, one which displays all contacts and
        // one which filters contacts by a search query. If mSearchTerm is set
        // then a search query has been entered and the latter should be used.
        if(mSearchTerm == null){
            // Since there's no search string, use the content URI that searches the entire
            // Contacts table
            contentUri = ContactMobileNumbQuery.CONTENT_URI;
        }else{
            // Since there's a search string, use the special content Uri that searches the
            // Contacts table. The URI consists of a base Uri and the search string.
            contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mSearchTerm));
        }
        // Returns a new CursorLoader for querying the Contacts table. No arguments are used
        // for the selection clause. The search string is either encoded onto the content URI,
        // or no contacts search string is used. The other search criteria are constants. See
        // the ContactsQuery interface.
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.PROJECTION,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.SELECTION,
                null,
                ContactMobileNumbQuery.SORT_ORDER);
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateLoader - incorrect ID provided (" + id + ")");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // This swaps the new cursor into the adapter.
    if(loader.getId() == ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID){
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    if(loader.getId() == ContactMobileNumbQuery.QUERY_ID){
        // When the loader is being reset, clear the cursor from the adapter. This allows the
        // cursor resources to be freed.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}

 /**
 * This is a subclass of CursorAdapter that supports binding Cursor columns to a view layout.
 * If those items are part of search results, it will be bind to the view layout.
 */
private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater; // Stores the layout inflater
     private TextAppearanceSpan highlightTextSpan; // Stores the highlight text appearance style

     /**
      * Instantiates a new Contacts Adapter.
      * @param context A context that has access to the app's layout.
      */
     public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
         super(context, null, 0);

        // Stores inflater for use later
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

     }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Binds data from the Cursor to the provided view.
     */
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Gets handles to individual view resources
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        final String displayName = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final String mobileNumb = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.NUMBER);

        final int startIndex = indexOfSearchQuery(displayName);
         if (startIndex == -1) {
                // If the user didn't do a search, or the search string didn't match a display
                // name, show the display name without highlighting
                holder.text1.setText(displayName);  
                holder.mobile_text.setText(mobileNumb);

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)) {

                } else {

                }
            }else {
                // If the search string matched the display name, applies a SpannableString to
                // highlight the search string with the displayed display name

                // Wraps the display name in the SpannableString
                final SpannableString highlightedName = new SpannableString(displayName);

                // Sets the span to start at the starting point of the match and end at "length"
                // characters beyond the starting point
                highlightedName.setSpan(highlightTextSpan, startIndex,
                        startIndex + mSearchTerm.length(), 0);

                // Binds the SpannableString to the display name View object
                holder.text1.setText(highlightedName);
            }
    }


    private int indexOfSearchQuery(String displayName) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)) {
            return displayName.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).indexOf(
                    mSearchTerm.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Overrides newView() to inflate the list item views.
     */
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
         // Inflates the list item layout.
        final View itemLayout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_view_item, viewGroup,false);

        // Creates a new ViewHolder in which to store handles to each view resource. This
        // allows bindView() to retrieve stored references instead of calling findViewById for
        // each instance of the layout.

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        holder.mobile_text = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.mobile_text);

        // Stores the resourceHolder instance in itemLayout. This makes resourceHolder
        // available to bindView and other methods that receive a handle to the item view.
        itemLayout.setTag(holder);

        // Returns the item layout view
        return itemLayout;
    }
}

/**
 * A class that defines fields for each resource ID in the list item layout. This allows
 * ContactsAdapter.newView() to store the IDs once, when it inflates the layout, instead of
 * calling findViewById in each iteration of bindView.
 */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView mobile_text;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by any activity that loads this fragment. When an
 * interaction occurs, such as touching an item from the ListView, these callbacks will
 * be invoked to communicate the event back to the activity.
 */
public interface OnContactsInteractionListener {
    /**
     * Called when a contact is selected from the ListView.
     * @param contactUri The contact Uri.
     */
    public void onContactSelected(String name, String mobile);

    /**
     * Called when the ListView selection is cleared like when
     * a contact search is taking place or is finishing.
     */
    public void onSelectionCleared();

    // Uses callback to notify activity this contains this fragment   
}
/**
 * This interface defines constants used by mobile number retrieval queries.
 */
public interface ContactMobileNumbQuery{
    final static int QUERY_ID = 1;

    //A Content Uri for Phone table
    final static Uri CONTENT_URI = Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    //The search or filter query Uri
    final static Uri FILTER_URI = Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;

    final static String SELECTION = Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + " AND " + Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "<>''";

    final static String SORT_ORDER = Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY;

    final static String[] PROJECTION = {
        Phone._ID,
        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
        Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        Phone.NUMBER,
        Phone.TYPE,
        SORT_ORDER
    };

    final static int ID = 0;
    final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 1;
    final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 2;
    final static int HAS_PHONE = 3;
    final static int NUMBER = 4;
    final static int TYPE = 5;
}
```

}

Can somebody help me to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code fixes my issue.

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Gets handles to individual view resources
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        final String displayName = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final String mobileNumb = cursor.getString(ContactMobileNumbQuery.NUMBER);

        holder.text1.setText(displayName);  
        holder.mobile_text.setText(mobileNumb);
    }
```